# How to pass request headers through to graphql resolvers

Tags: node.js, jwt, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I have a graphql endpoint which is authorised by a JWT. My JWT strategy verifies the JWT then adds the user object to the request object.

In a restful route, I would access my users' data like so:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('user', req.user)
}
```

I want to access req.user object within my graphql resolver in order to extract the users' ID. However, when I try log the `context` variable, it is always empty.

Do I need to configure my graphql endpoint to pass through the `req` data to the resolver?

My app.js has my graphql set up like this:

```
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';

app.use('/graphql', [passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), bodyParser.json()], graphqlExpress({ schema }));
```

Then I have my resolvers like so:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: { 
    user: async (obj, {email}, context) => {
        console.log('obj', obj) // undefined
      console.log('email', email) // currently passed through in graphql query but I want to replace this with the user data passed in req / context
        console.log('context', context) // {}
        return await UserService.findOne(email)
    },
};

// Put together a schema
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
```

How can I access my JWT user data in my resolvers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently you need to pass through context manually like so:

```
app.use('/graphql', [auth_middleware, bodyParser.json()], (req, res) => graphqlExpress({ schema, context: req.user })(req, res) );
```

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/420) if anybody is interested: